# Powershell почему не воспринимает команду?

Tags: powershell, windows-7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько понял нужно установить командлеты группы net но как найти не могу

Comment: В 10-ке Pro работает без дополнительных настроек, проверил

Comment: https://info-comp.ru/sisadminst/555-directory-windows-powershell-cmdlets.html#WorkingWithHyperVInPS